# Firebase Storage and AppCheck too many unverified requests

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, firebase-app-check

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

The situation is as above, I register the urls of the uploaded images in the database and print them like that, could this be the case?

Am I doing something wrong with the parameters in the urls I've drawn as follows?

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/xxx/o/20267567567221.webp?alt=media&token=2667a8d4-7d1b-40df-8584-4af0673d4995
```

In this way, I save the url it pressed to the database.

```
taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadUrl) {
   //Here I am registering the url to the database
 });
```

This is how I show the picture

```
CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: images)
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/custom-resource#send_app_check_tokens_with_backend_requests

```
final appCheckToken = await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.getToken();
    if (appCheckToken != null) {
        final response = await http.get(
            Uri.parse("https://yourbackend.example.com/yourExampleEndpoint"),
            headers: {"X-Firebase-AppCheck": appCheckToken},
        );
    } else {
        // Error: couldn't get an App Check token.
    }
```

I didn't send any app check token, just do I need to send it so I added it

Should I follow a path like here? It seems silly to me because when I pull the url directly it seems like it should send it itself automatically..

What I want to know is if the standard download url is used in an application with a properly configured appcheck plugin, is it verifed or unverifed?

Comment: could you attach your code too, the ones when you send **HTTP GET** request

Comment: Are you doing this within an **async** function?

Comment: As per firebase, they say ```don't send App Check tokens as part of URLs, including in query parameters, as this makes them vulnerable to accidental leakage and interception```. I believe you are actually sending in the tokens in the `token` parameter in your URL that way, this could be the reason that Firebase is rejecting them.

Comment: No, I'm not sending, I'm asking if I should send it because there is always an invalid request.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Since I save the urls in the database, I need to send a header, I made it a provider and used it this way.

```
CachedNetworkImage(httpHeaders: {
      "X-Firebase-AppCheck":
          Provider.of<AppCheckProvider>(context, listen: false).token
    }, imageUrl: images);
```